# Django 'endfor', expected 'endblock'

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to learn Django but keep receiving the error " 'endfor', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? " when I add the {% for key,value in
price.DISPLAY.items %} {{ key }} {% endfor %} part of the code. How can I fix this? Any help would be great thanks.

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %} {% for key,value in
price.DISPLAY.items %} {{ key }} {% endfor %}

<br />
<br />

{{ price.DISPLAY }}
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    {% for info in api.Data %}
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
      <img src="{{info.imageurl}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{info.source}}" />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{info.title}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{info.body}}</p>
        <a href="{{info.url}}" class="btn btn-secondary" target="_blank"
          >Read more</a
        >
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>

{{ api.Data }} {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: A template tag should not span multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A template tag should not span multiple lines. You should write the `{% for … %}` tag on a single line:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}
{% for key,value in price.DISPLAY.items %} {{ key }} {% endfor %}
    …
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man that works perfectly now, I'm using VS Code and Prettier was changing it to that format when I saved it. Uninstalled it and it's fine now, cheers.